# How do I secure a Python API with in-the-open authorization tokens?

Tags: python, rest, flask, django-rest-framework, authorization

I have setup a simple REST API server (using Django REST framework) that responds to POST requests by doing some processing on an image uploaded to the server in the request. Previously I used it to power my own frontend (http://lips.kyleingraham.com) as a demonstration but I would now like to open the API to other users.

I would like for an end-user to be able to sign up and, from a dashboard, generate a token based on their credentials that could then be hard-coded into their web app. The sign-up part I believe I can handle but I am unclear on how to restrict a generated token to a user's web app domain. I know that the code for a web app is easily inspected so any API token I provide would need to be policed on my backend.

How can I restrict an authorization token to a users' web app domain so that even if the token was leaked, another user would not be able to utilize it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hard-code url into user web app, in that way you can't guarantee that if someone get the token, he won't be able to use it.

The only idea is to set some time limit for each token